# IS Add to Homescreen feature enabled in IPhone IOS12

Tags: ios, iphone, progressive-web-apps

Progressive Web Apps on iOS are here

https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7

My question here is, can i add my pwa app to ios devices or iphone to homescreen just like in android chrome browser.

Here I am not looking the feature in safari, but on chrome atlease

Comment: Have someone you know with an iPhone OS12 try it with the PWA sample here https://airhorner.com/

Comment: Have you had any chance to check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302780/ios-12-pwa-support)?